# win32gui.FindWindow not returning correct values

Tags: python, python-2.7, winapi, win32gui

So I always used this code to find window position/sizes and today I tried to locate the Memu (an android emulator) window.

This code :

```
def print_memu_position():
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "MEmu")
    left, top, right, bottom = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    print "topleft_xy = {},{}".format(left, top)
    print "bottomright_xy = {},{}".format(right, bottom)
    print "width = {}".format(right-left)
    print "height = {}".format(bottom-top)
```

prints :

```
topleft_xy = 3635,881
bottomright_xy = 3714,925
width = 79
height = 44
```

which is not correct the Memu window is 574x982

I'm using 3 screens but it should not be a problem because when I use this code to find something else, Vysor for example that miror a phone screen on your computer I get correct results.

Here is what was found visually :

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve the problem?
Thanks

## EDIT :

this code does find the MEmu hwnd

```
def printMemuHwnd():

    def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            if win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) == "MEmu":
                print (hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
                left, top, right, bottom = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
                print "topleft_xy = {},{}".format(left, top)
                print "bottomright_xy = {},{}".format(right, bottom)
                print "width = {}".format(right - left)
                print "height = {}".format(bottom - top)

    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)
```

and with `GetForegroundWindow()` I get the correct dimension.

so why won't `hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "MEmu")` work?

Comment: You can use `GetForegroundWindow()` to get the hwnd of `Menu` window.

Comment: it works @jizhihaoSAMA, but why? after `GetForegroundWindow()` if I do `print "["+win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)+ "]"` I get `[MEmu]` which is what I was using

Comment: Hmmm,So maybe you need to use `FindWindow(None, "MEmu")`?

Comment: same result with MEmu, I made I typo while putting the code here

Comment: [FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindoww) takes *two* arguments. Trying to find a window by window title only is the most brittle option you could ever consider.

Comment: Is the `MEmu` window handle obtained using `FindWindow` the same as that obtained by `GetForegroundWindow`?  Have you tested other windows?